# how can define bounds for " optimize.minimize" in python?

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have function with some variable :

```
def objective(x):
     #= params
    x00 = x[0]
    y00 = x[1]
    u_m = x[2]
    a = x[3]
    b = x[4]
    u_mean_real = x[5]
    A = x[6]

    B = x[7]
    H = x[8]
    alpha = x[9]
    .
    .
    .
    .    


    A1 = interpolating_spline(1, x, DataPointsDomain, DataPointsRange)
    B = 6.6
    H = 1
    x00 = 0.5  
    y00 = 0.85806221   
    u_mean_real =0.957175
    u_m=1.2

    u_max = 1.287
    .
    .
    .
```

I need to define "bound" for "optimize.minimize" and i define "A1" for variable of "A" ,  ,but i do not know the range of "A" value

how should i do that ?

I want to minimize a function just by specifying the value of the three variables of the function("a" , "b","alpha") that the range of these variables =(1,5), and define the other variables of the function as a number or some function

please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know both bounds of your variable, you can specify with a None value, that it is unbounded in that direction. For example for the variable A it would be `(A1, None)`, and you can give all bounds as a list of touples (or as a Bounds instance - only in newer versions of Scipy)